# How to get the subject , verb and object from a complex sentence consisting of more than one verb and preposition?

Tags: java, data-structures, nlp, predicate, subject

Previously I differentiated using the *(NOUN)(VERB)(NOUN) RELATIONSHIP*,

For example, it works well with:

```
(John) (went) (to the market)
```

My source code:

```
str = John went to the market
splited_str = str.split(" ")
String subject, verb, object;
Boolean flag = true;
for i=0 to i<splited_str.length
  if (!isVerb(splited_str[i]) && flag)
     subject += splited_str[i] + " "
  if (isVerb)
     flag = false
     verb = splited_str[i]
  else
     object += splited_str[i] + " "
```

But my code fails, for complex sentences, like this one:

```
It is up to us to find the answer.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a difficult problem in computational linguistics, and too broad for a forum like Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stanford CoreNLP OpenIE to extract this type of triplet.

When you use OpenIE in your Java, just add the annotator openie to your properties.

See [this example from Stanford](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/openie.html) or [this answer which uses a command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53445226/10017823) for examples of using triplets.

After you figure out the triplets you can remove triplets that are subsets of others to get only the more specific triplets.