# How to pick out a the subject, predicate, and object and adjectives in a sentence

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to extract the subject, predicate, and object of a sentence and find out which adjectives go to the subject, predicate, or object with Stanford CoreNLP in java code.

I have tried to use the dependency parser to solve this by finding the dependency index, checking the dependency tag if it equals amod, then adding it to an ArrayList, but with this method sometimes the adjective's dependency tag is not amod and is nmod, and other tags may come up.

With determining the object and predicate, I have used a similar method as above. I have checked if it is det, and if it is any other tags that mean it is a predicate or object. However, sometimes different tags come up and it is not efficient to have to parse every tag that somewhat means it is a predicate pointing to the object.

So my question is, how to I get the subject, predicate, and object of a sentence and each's adjectives but not need to check each tag?

For the above mentioned attempts, I have used Stanford CoreNLP Simple API, but I am OK with the standard API if it is truly needed.

Comment: Sentences are not as simple as 'a subject, and object, and a predicate' in the model of CoreNLP. There is no more efficient process than to have many rules that look for the sentence patterns you are interested in, or a trained model that selects trees that you care about.

Comment: Is there a library that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try out the `openie` annotator which will find (subject, predicate, object) triples.

example command:

```
java -Xmx5g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,coref,natlog,openie -file basic-example.txt -outputFormat text
```

example:

```
The tall man ate the delicious pizza.
```

example output:

```
1.0     man     ate     pizza
1.0     man     ate     delicious pizza
1.0     tall man        ate     pizza
1.0     tall man        ate     delicious pizza
```

Comment: Why do we need 14 GB memory for OpenIE?

Comment: It shouldn't need 14Gb memory. I expect it to use between 1-2GB (2-3 if you have the `coref` annotator included), with 4GB being pretty safe for most applications.

Comment: Our entire pipeline with every annotator needs something like 14GB so that is what I put by default, but yes I'm sure it works with considerably less.